# How do I update the Android UI using AWS TransferManager in a ProgressListener?

Tags: android, multithreading, amazon-web-services

I'm using AWS TransferManager to download files to the SD card. It allows for a ProgressListener, but I can't update the view because it is on a different thread. How can I do this?

The btn.setText() method below produces this warning and doesn't update the UI:

> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

```
public class Download
{

   ProgressDialog    dialog;
   File              new_video_file;
   Button            btn;              //the progress meter needs to know what button called this. set via setter method below.
   int               position;

   protected void start(int position, Button btn) 
   {
      this.btn            = (Button) btn;
      this.position       = position;
      this.new_video_file = new File(storage_dir, arr_videos.get(position));                   //local file to be writtent to


      AWSCredentials credentials                             = new BasicAWSCredentials("xxx", "xxx" );
      TransferManager tx                                     = new TransferManager(credentials);

      Log.v("s3_bucket", s3_bucket); 
      Log.v("s3_dir", s3_dir); 
      Log.v("name", arr_videos.get(position)); 

      final com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.Download download   = tx.download(s3_bucket, s3_dir + arr_videos.get(position), new_video_file);

      download.addProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {

          public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent pe) {
              Double progress = download.getProgress().getPercentTransfered();

              String percent = progress.intValue() + "%";

              Log.v("progress", percent);

              btn.setText(percent);

              if (download.isDone()) {
                  Log.v("dev", "download complete!!!");
              }
          }
      });

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Handler` object that is created on UI thread, so it will receive call to `handleMessage` or `Runnable.run()` on that thread.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do it.

- Try Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable), View.post(Runnable), View.postDelayed(Runnable, long)
- Use Handler or AsyncTask. Here is an [example](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxETGTFNJ28MO9/Making-Asynchronous-Calls-with-AsyncTask) that uploads a file to S3 with AmazonS3Client.putObject and sends update to a dialog box.

You can find more information about threads [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html). Hope this helps.